# How to serialize a list of strings

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm having an rather easy problem with my serializer. 
My view:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_recipes_list(request):
    recipes = Recipe.objects.all()

    serializer = RecipeListSerializer(recipes, context={'request': request}, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

My serializer:

```
class RecipeListSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
```

Output I'm getting:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Gelato1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Gelato2"
    },
]
```

What I desire is:

```
[
    'name': [
       'Gelato1',
       'Gelato2',
    ] 
]
```

I tried: `recipes = Recipe.objects.all().values_list('name', flat=True)`
So that the QuerySet has a list of names, but I'm getting an AttributeError.
I'll be grateful for any advices.

Comment: Could you try this : `recipes =list(Recipe.objects.values_list('name', flat=True`

Comment: AttributeError: Original exception text was: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'.

Comment: If you usw this query, you shouldn't use serializer. Did you use serializer?

Comment: Alright! Seems like I overdid it! All there had to be done was to `return Response(recipes)`. Thanks!

Comment: Okey, I'm adding this as an answer for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use values_list with flat attribute, you don't need to  pass it to serializer.For your output, you can add result to Response :

```
recipes =list(Recipe.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
return Response({'output':recipes})
```